# UICollectionView weird cells animation when dismiss mode of the keyboard is interactive

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to achieve a chat system using `UICollectionView` -The collectionview is turned upside down and so are the cells using `CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1)-` and so far everything is going well, I'm calculating cell sizes manually using `NSString.boundingRect` and it's working as expected, then I enabled the collectionview's interactive keyboard dismissal since then whenever I drag the keyboard a little bit then I let go it results into a really weird animation which I can't seem to figure out what's triggering it.

I also use `Typist` which is a small utility class that facilitates keyboard handling https://github.com/totocaster/Typist, I'm not really suspecting it since it is a simple wrapper `UIKeyboard` notifications.

I've tried several stuff including but not limited to

1-Disabling animations when showing cell using 
`UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)` then enabling it again just before returning the cell which did not work.

2-Removing the upside-down approach altogether, and again nope even when it's in a normal transform the bug still occurs

3-Rewrote the entire `UICollectionView` implementation to `UITableView` implementation which -surprisingly- yielded a better result the weird animation isn't as strong as it's on the `UICollectionView` but it's still happening to some extent

4-Removing Typist altogether and reverting back to `NotificationCenter` and manual handling and nope, does not work.

UICollectionView initialization

```swift
    lazy var chatCollectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let collectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        collectionViewFlowLayout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: collectionViewFlowLayout)
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
        collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView.register(OutgoingTextCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: OutgoingTextCell.className)
        collectionView.register(IncomingTextCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: IncomingTextCell.className)
        collectionView.register(OutgoingImageCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: OutgoingImageCell.className)
        collectionView.register(IncomingImageCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: IncomingImageCell.className)
        collectionView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)
        collectionView.semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
        collectionView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
        return collectionView
    }()
```

UICollectionView DataSource / Delete implementation

```swift
extension ChatViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return presenter.numberOfRows
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if presenter.isSender(at: indexPath) {
            switch presenter.messageType(at: indexPath) {
            case .text:

                let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: OutgoingTextCell.className, for: indexPath) as! OutgoingTextCell
                presenter.configure(cell: AnyConfigurableCell(cell), at: indexPath)
                return cell

            case .photo:

                let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: OutgoingImageCell.className, for: indexPath) as! OutgoingImageCell
                presenter.configure(cell: AnyConfigurableCell(cell), at: indexPath)
                return cell
            }
        } else {
            switch presenter.messageType(at: indexPath) {
            case .text:

                let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: IncomingTextCell.className, for: indexPath) as! IncomingTextCell
                presenter.configure(cell: AnyConfigurableCell(cell), at: indexPath)
                return cell

            case .photo:

                let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: IncomingImageCell.className, for: indexPath) as! IncomingImageCell
                presenter.configure(cell: AnyConfigurableCell(cell), at: indexPath)
                return cell
            }
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        if presenter.messageType(at: indexPath) == .photo {
            return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 250)
        } else {
            if let height = cachedSizes[presenter.uuidForMessage(at: indexPath)] {
                return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: height)
            } else {
                let height = calculateTextHeight(at: indexPath)
                cachedSizes[presenter.uuidForMessage(at: indexPath)] = height
                return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: height)
            }
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 0, bottom: 8, right: 0)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row == presenter.numberOfRows - 1 && !isPaginating {
            presenter.loadNextPage()
        }
    }

    private func calculateTextHeight(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        let approximateSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width - 88, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        let estimatedHeight = NSString(string: presenter.contentForMessage(at: indexPath)).boundingRect(with: approximateSize, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [.font: DinNextFont.regular.getFont(ofSize: 14)], context: nil).height
        return estimatedHeight + 40
    }

}
```

Cell implementation

```swift
class OutgoingTextCell: UICollectionViewCell, ConfigurableCell {

    lazy var containerView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = .coral
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        return view
    }()

    lazy var contentLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.textColor = .white
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.font = DinNextFont.regular.getFont(ofSize: 14)
        return label
    }()

    private lazy var stackView: UIStackView = {
        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [timeLabel, checkMarkImageView])
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.axis = .horizontal
        stackView.distribution = .equalSpacing
        stackView.alignment = .center
        stackView.spacing = 4
        return stackView
    }()

    private lazy var checkMarkImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "ic_check")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate))
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.tintColor = .white
        imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 8).isActive = true
        imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10).isActive = true
        return imageView
    }()

    lazy var timeLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.textColor = .white
        label.font = DinNextFont.regular.getFont(ofSize: 10)
        label.text = "12:14"
        return label
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        layoutUI()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private func addSubviews() {
        addSubview(containerView)
        containerView.addSubview(contentLabel)
        containerView.addSubview(stackView)
    }

    func setupContainerViewConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 0),
            containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -8),
            containerView.widthAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 100),
            containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 34),
            containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 64)
        ])
    }

    private func setupContentLabelConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            contentLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: 4),
            contentLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8),
            contentLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8),
        ])
    }

    private func setupStackViewConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -6),
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -4),
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 6),
            stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20),
        ])
    }

    private func layoutUI() {
        addSubviews()
        setupContainerViewConstraints()
        setupContentLabelConstraints()
        setupStackViewConstraints()
    }

    func configure(model: MessageViewModel) {
        containerView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)
        contentLabel.text = model.content
        timeLabel.text = model.time
        checkMarkImageView.isHidden = !model.isSent
    }
}
```

The output of UICollectionView is as the following

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RajfZk5lGCQ

The output of the UITableview is as the following

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ayG7WhYKXo

It might not be really clear but if you look closely you can see the cells are "briefly" animating and with longer messages it looks kind of "sliding animation" which does not leak appealing at all.

Comment: In collectionview case you'll mostly need a custom class of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and inside it you'll cache the layout for the shown list, so collection won't have to repeat the process of laying out.

Comment: I'm already caching the heights of cells in order to stop the collectionview from calculating cell heights every time, isn't that sufficient ? and why would a subclass of UICollectionViewFlowLayout improve this ?

Comment: caching in the flow is `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` cache, which is much more than height calculation

Comment: Okay I'm going to implement a simple UICollectionViewLayout subclass and report back with the result.

Comment: As advised I wrote my own implementation of UICollectionViewLayout which can be found at this gist: https://gist.github.com/tareksabry1337/874e107a68c80547414620e3b966f413
Yet the problem still persists

Comment: The result of the previous gist can be seen at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UyVbBr1qC4s which shows that absolutely nothing has changed.

Comment: @TarekSabry I'm getting the same annoying behavior...were you able to solve it?